# How to show email prefilled in google oauth sign in form

Tags: wso2, google-oauth, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 as identity server and google authenticator as the identity provider. Login is working correctly. On my web application, I am asking the user to enter his email and then showing google login form. I want to show this email to be prefilled this form. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it. For that, you need to customize the OpenIDConnectAuthenticator.java to pass the login_hint to google.

- Clone https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-oidc.git.

It is recommended to checkout to the org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.oidc version in your server(you can find it in IS_HOME/repository/components/dropins/)

- Add these lines before `response.sendRedirect(loginPage);` in OpenIDConnectAuthenticator.java

  ```
          String[] usernames = context.getAuthenticationRequest().getRequestQueryParam("username");
          if (usernames != null && usernames.length > 0) {
              loginPage = loginPage + "&login_hint=" + usernames[0];
          }
  ```

These lines will get the username from the authentication initiation request and send it as login_hint to google.

- Build the component using the following command.

`mvn clean install`

This will create org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.oidc-5.1.17.jar in target folder.

- Replace the existing org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.oidc-.jar in the IS_HOME/repository/components/dropins folder.
- Restart the IS server
- When sending authentication request to IS append `username=senthalank@gmail.com` as url param

For example,
`https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<cliend_id>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/playground2/oauth2client&scope=openid&username=senthalank@gmail.com`